# Platform-Independent Python Stream/Audio Module

Tags: python, audio, stream, multiplatform, webradio

Currently I am working on a Python-Programm which streams (i.e. plays) Webradio-Audio-Streams. Since I am implementing this with gstreamer, it is not platform-independent.

Unfortunately, it seems I am unable to find such a module or framework which is platform-independent and **not deprecated**.

Could you give me some hints?

Greetings.